# AsynckTask in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, asyncsocket

i want to use the same socket address for multiple calls for this task.

i tried to get the address from different class but didn't work .

please help !!!

my call from different class is:

```
new ConnectToServer().execute(ip, "2000", "br1");
```

my code for task is:

```
public class ConnectToServer extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... parms) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            Socket s = new Socket(parms[0], Integer.parseInt(parms[1]));
            // ******

            OutputStream os = s.getOutputStream();
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(os);

            if (parms[2] == "br1") {
                out.write("rr1".getBytes());
                out.write('\n');
                out.flush();
            } else if (parms[2] == "br2") {

                out.write("rr2".getBytes());
                out.write('\n');
                out.flush();
            } else if (parms[2] == "br3") {
                out.write("rr3".getBytes());
                out.write('\n');
                out.flush();
            } else if (parms[2] == "br4") {
                out.write("rr4".getBytes());
                out.write('\n');
                out.flush();
            } else if (parms[2] == "bb1") {
                out.write("bb1".getBytes());
                out.write('\n');
                out.flush();
            } else if (parms[2] == "bb2") {
                out.write("bb2".getBytes());
                out.write('\n');
                out.flush();
            } else if (parms[2] == "bb3") {
                out.write("bb3".getBytes());
                out.write('\n');
                out.flush();
            } else if (parms[2] == "bb4") {
                out.write("bb4".getBytes());
                out.write('\n');
                out.flush();
            }

            // s.shutdownOutput();

        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: `parms[2] == "br1"`. Not good. Search for how to compare Strings in Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compare java `String`s with `String == String`. You need to use `String.equals(String)` instead.

Try this code:

```
        if (parms[2].equals("br1")) {
            out.write("rr1".getBytes());
            out.write('\n');
            out.flush();
        } else if (parms[2].equals("br2")) {

            out.write("rr2".getBytes());
            out.write('\n');
            out.flush();
        } else if (parms[2].equals("br3")) {
            out.write("rr3".getBytes());
            out.write('\n');
            out.flush();
        } else if (parms[2].equals("br4")) {
            out.write("rr4".getBytes());
            out.write('\n');
            out.flush();
        } else if (parms[2].equals("bb1")) {
            out.write("bb1".getBytes());
            out.write('\n');
            out.flush();
        } else if (parms[2].equals("bb2")) {
            out.write("bb2".getBytes());
            out.write('\n');
            out.flush();
        } else if (parms[2].equals("bb3")) {
            out.write("bb3".getBytes());
            out.write('\n');
            out.flush();
        } else if (parms[2].equals("bb4")) {
            out.write("bb4".getBytes());
            out.write('\n');
            out.flush();
        }
```

Comment: i talk about the socket not String.

Comment: Please give a stack trace or a more in-depth explanation of what's wrong.

Comment: sorry i am beginner,,, when i call this class (new ConnectToServer().execute(ip, "2000", "br1");)....it is create new socket    ,when i recall its create new socket and so on , i want to use the same address for all calls?? your correct code should solve                                 Socket s=***THE CORRECT***new Socket(ip,port);